# Debugging TS files in a Browser

Tags: angular, debugging, browser, angular9

I'm currently using the latest version of Angular and I've started coding a simple project. I've reached a point where I need to dubug some lines of code so I opened, as I've always done so far, the dev tools of Chrome trying to file the file. Sadly the are none.

Am I missing something or what? It seems that the compiler doesn't build up the sourceMap files related.

If someone need it, here's my `package.json` file for the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/common": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.0.0-rc.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.0-rc.9",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.18.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.4"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that in the `configurations` in the `angular.json` file I had the serve configuration using the build config to work. The build configuration have the `sourceMap` setted to false.

I've changed to true and it's working perfectly.

Comment: What do you mean by " had the serve configuration using the build config to work", tnx

Comment: Hi, I can't really remember the situation I was in, but reading my question and the comment I'd assume I was using a configuration for serving that had the SM setted to false thus I wasn't able to see the files in the dev tools in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found following working for me.

Change the angular.json file and add following configurations, look that you insert the configs on the right path on the right indentation in the file:

```
  "projects": {
    "yourprojectname": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
            ...
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "yourprojectname:build",
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "yourprojectname:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "yourprojectname:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        ...
        ...
        ...
       }
     }
   }
```

I hope it makes things clearer.